# Creating radial images with CSS

Tags: html, css

when implementing images on a page, I want to put them in a circle like

[image: Circle]

but their default form is a rectangle. I want to change their form to a circle. **Example**:

```html
<p>
Current:
</p>

<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/316916526760591362/392232736468762625/unknown.png">

<p>
Desired:
</p>

<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/316916526760591362/392237925942951936/unknown.png">
```

How can I do this?

Comment: border-radius !!!

Comment: What do you mean uploading images?

Comment: @Highdef sorry, I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a border radius should be what you are asking.

```css
img{
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/128/128/animals?t=1513587750720"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way

```
img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `border-radius:50%` to `img`

```css
img {
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<p>
Current:
</p>

<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/316916526760591362/392232736468762625/unknown.png">

<p>
Desired:
</p>

<img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/316916526760591362/392237925942951936/unknown.png">
```